# Error when running a basic webpage with Zurb Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I've download the complete package of [Zurb Foundation For Sites](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) and I get the following error:

```
foundation.js:11621 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__home_deployer_sites_node_foundation_customizer_node_foundation_customizer_foundation_sites_js_foundation_core__.a.addToJQuery is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (foundation.js:11621)
    at __webpack_require__ (foundation.js:20)
    at module.exports (foundation.js:66)
    at foundation.js:69
```

My code:

```
 <script src="/Foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>    
 <script src="/Foundation/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
 <script src="/Foundation/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>    

<script>
   $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

When I run foundation.min.js instead of foundation.js it gives me:

```
foundation.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: o.a.addToJQuery is not a function
```

I tried to replace tje jQuery library with a CDN one, still the same issue.

Double checked, all file exist. Developing locally. **Using Zurb Foundation 6.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved now

If you have an older version of npm (3) or older then you likely will see this. In npm 4 the way dependancies are loaded changed.

Here is more info from the Foundation forum: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53331-fresh-64-download-js-errors

Answer (score 1):

There are posts on the Foundation forum about this [Issue](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/53331-fresh-64-download-js-errors), but I haven't seen a response.  Try installing from NPM, or roll back to 6.3.1 version which works great.